# How to redirect a list of files to sed and modify them inplace?

Tags: sed, grep, pipe

I would like to do sth like this:

```
grep --files-with-matches <pattern> * | sed -i <pattern>
```

Which means: take a list of files generated by grep and modify each of them inplace.
Is it possible in one-liner ?

Comment: Where is that the `grep` recieves input from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep -l <pattern> * | xargs sed -i 's/replaceFrom/replaceTo/g'
```